# Laravel WHERE query against NULL column not working. Bug?

Tags: mysql, laravel

If the model table has a column with a `null` value, we cannot query against it by using `where` clauses.

For example,

`Model::where('status', '!=', 'something');`
`Model::whereNotIn('status', ['something']);`

Both return an empty collection, even tho there is clearly records with status `null`

Laravel version: `6.17.1`

Any workarounds?

Comment: have you try whereNull('status') ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Model::whereNull('status')
->orWhere('status', 'something')
->get();
```

which will fetch records where column status is either `null` or status is equal to `something`

Comment: This is the answer. Especially, if we use `Parameter Grouping` so the `orWhere` do not mess up the query

Comment: However, it is still sad that if the value can be ´something_else_2` in the future, we have to edit this query. It would be cool to be able to use `whereNotIn`

Comment: I ended up using this inside `parameter grouping`:
`$builder->whereNull('status')->orWhereNotIn('status', ['value', 'value_2']);`

Answer (score 0):

As per [Laravel Documenation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses)

```
whereNull / whereNotNull / orWhereNull / orWhereNotNull
```

> The `whereNull` method verifies that the value of the given column is
>   NULL:

You can use `whereNull` to check the null values in a column

```
Model::whereNull("status");
```

Comment: Yes, but what if the column can be a `null` and `something_else`

Comment: It would be better if we could query against the `null` value

Comment: You can use orWhere for the same `->orWhere('status', 'something')`

Comment: However, it is still sad that if the value can be `something_else_2` in the future, we have to edit this query. It would be cool to be able to use `whereNotIn`

Comment: Anyway, I think I have to use `orWhere` with `parameter grouping`